# Get OS name with C [Linux, portable for distros: Centos, Debian, Fedora, OpenSUSE, RedHat, Ubuntu]

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I know I can check my OS name with this simple command: `lsb_release -ds`. But I also know, that its not portable on all platforms where I need it. I tried `struct utsname info;` and `uname(&info)` and it works great but gives me only "base" name - "Linux".

Is there any portable (C) way of getting full OS name? Portable between Centos, Debian, Fedora, OpenSUSE, RedHat, Ubuntu at least? Cheers

Comment: Why exactly do you ask? Can't you just use `uname` syscall? Why? (in other words, why is it so important to guess from a *C* program if your Linux is Debian or Mint or Gentoo)

Comment: Also see [Best way to find os name and version in unix/linux platform](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26988262/608639).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uname` system call gives you the generic system type (`Linux` in all your cases) in the `sysname` field, but it also gives you additional data in the `release`, `version`, and `machine` fields.  The `release` field will give you the kernel version, and the `version` field will give you the general system version, which will be different for all the various linux variants you mention.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the C code that says the name of the OS. You can also edit the code for other various purpose, by using the same logic.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[50] = " ";
    fp = popen("lsb_release -ds", "r");
    fgets(buffer, 50, fp);
    pclose(fp);
    printf("Name of the OS is : %s",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: should better be `/usr/bin/lsb_release` not just `lsb_release` (the user might have changed his `PATH`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ya you can give any command, I just have shown the way it can be done.

Comment: Fedora doesnt have lsb_release by default ;)

Answer (score 3):

LSB in name `lsb_release` states for "Linux Standard Base", but doesn't so standard.

I came to the following code: https://github.com/myaut/tsload/blob/master/agent/lib/libhostinfo/plat/linux/uname.c

It checks:

- `/etc/oracle-release` for Oracle Enterprise Linux
- `/etc/redhat-release` for RHEL other derivatives
- `/etc/SuSE-release` for SuSE derivatives
- `lsb_release` output for any other Linux

It also cuts out irrelevant words i.e. `CentOS release 6.3 (Final)` -> `CentOS 6.3`

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to run and read the output of command `/usr/bin/lsb_release -ds`. If that fails, you might read and parse `/etc/issue`

<sup>Notice that clever or paranoid sysadmins might edit and configure that `/etc/issue` file at will.</sup>

But I don't understand why you want to know all that (from inside a *C* program), in other words, why the `uname` syscall is not enough.

In particular, there are a lot of Debian (or Redhat) derived specialized distributions, and I don't understand why the name of the particular distribution would matter to a *C* program. It matters much more for packaging purposes....

Comment: yup, I used `popen` for this but Im concered about oses that dont have `lsb_release` :) Is `/etc/issue` availible on all OSes I asked about?

Comment: Ok, I should choose an easier way, I will cat `/etc/issue` ;) But is it availible on EVERY OS I asked about?

Comment: maybe the c program doesn't care at all... its the user that's being catered to.

Comment: I have recently seen a system where /etc/issue was indeed heavily edited, and didn't contain any OS information any more. Not sure if /etc/issue.net was edited as well; it might be a viable fallback for you. Also, Debian/Ubuntu systems appear to have a /etc/debian_version file which you could consult.