# Best way to find the OS name and version on a Unix/Linux platform

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, version

I need to find the OS name and version on a Unix/Linux platform. For this I tried the following:

1. `lsb_release` utility
2. `/etc/redhat-release` or specific file

But it does not seem to be the best solution, as LSB_RELEASE support is no longer for [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) 7.

Is there a way that will work on any Unix or Linux platform?

Comment: This problem need heuristic approach, that's why I gave you a perl's snippet to run in a shell

Comment: lsb_release -d will work on ubuntu

Comment: `uname` is in most unix environments and guaranteed to be on every LSB compliant linux distro: http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_2.0.1/LSB-Core/LSB-Core/command.html

Comment: how to get os version for eg. redhat 6.5 using uname ?

Comment: @Niraj - By reading the manpage http://linux.die.net/man/1/uname and grokking its output (assuming it is supported in RH6.5) ... either way there is no (single) portable way to get this because it is mostly irrelevant info.  Portable programs should probe for required features, not use some whitelist of prechecked distros.

Comment: ``lsb_release -d`` works for Red Hat too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I identify the particular Linux flavor via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13036048/608639), [How to discover what Linux distribution is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/264290/608639), etc.

Comment: ON RH and derivatives, the command `/usr/bin/lsb_release` is provided by the package 'redhat-lsb-release'. However, it isn't required by the `redhat-release` or `centos-release` packages, and so isn't installed by default. Use `yum`/`dnf` to install it, and you're good.

Answer (score 150):

This work fine for all Linux environments.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
cat /etc/*-release
```

In Ubuntu:

```bash
$ cat /etc/*-release

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS"
```

Or [Ubuntu 12.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin):

```bash
$ cat /etc/*-release

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.4 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.4 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
```

In [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux):

```bash
$ cat /etc/*-release

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
```

Or use this script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# Detects which OS and if it is Linux then it will detect which Linux
# Distribution.

OS=`uname -s`
REV=`uname -r`
MACH=`uname -m`

GetVersionFromFile()
{
    VERSION=`cat $1 | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/.*VERSION.*=\ // `
}

if [ "${OS}" = "SunOS" ] ; then
    OS=Solaris
    ARCH=`uname -p`
    OSSTR="${OS} ${REV}(${ARCH} `uname -v`)"
elif [ "${OS}" = "AIX" ] ; then
    OSSTR="${OS} `oslevel` (`oslevel -r`)"
elif [ "${OS}" = "Linux" ] ; then
    KERNEL=`uname -r`
    if [ -f /etc/redhat-release ] ; then
        DIST='RedHat'
        PSUEDONAME=`cat /etc/redhat-release | sed s/.*\(// | sed s/\)//`
        REV=`cat /etc/redhat-release | sed s/.*release\ // | sed s/\ .*//`
    elif [ -f /etc/SuSE-release ] ; then
        DIST=`cat /etc/SuSE-release | tr "\n" ' '| sed s/VERSION.*//`
        REV=`cat /etc/SuSE-release | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/.*=\ //`
    elif [ -f /etc/mandrake-release ] ; then
        DIST='Mandrake'
        PSUEDONAME=`cat /etc/mandrake-release | sed s/.*\(// | sed s/\)//`
        REV=`cat /etc/mandrake-release | sed s/.*release\ // | sed s/\ .*//`
    elif [ -f /etc/debian_version ] ; then
        DIST="Debian `cat /etc/debian_version`"
        REV=""

    fi
    if [ -f /etc/UnitedLinux-release ] ; then
        DIST="${DIST}[`cat /etc/UnitedLinux-release | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/VERSION.*//`]"
    fi

    OSSTR="${OS} ${DIST} ${REV}(${PSUEDONAME} ${KERNEL} ${MACH})"

fi

echo ${OSSTR}
```

Comment: yeah you are right but i dont want to read it from *-release file.

Comment: i want some utility like lsb_realease

Comment: -1 : output on my archlinux is `Linux 3.16.4-1-ARCH( 3.16.4-1-ARCH x86_64)`

Comment: The script is useful but for linux it is showing ==Linux RedHat version(Final 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 x86_64) .my redhat version is 6.5 but it is not showing in output ?

Comment: I tested on RHEL6.3 It is showing output as  `Linux RedHat 6.3(Santiago 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64)`

Comment: What is the Output of this Command `cat /etc/redhat-release | sed s/.*\(// | sed s/\)//` in your RHEL 6.5

Comment: Note that ```[ -f /etc/redhat-release ]``` may not be sufficient. CentOS 7, for example, has symbolic links from /etc/redhat-release to /etc/centos-release. If one wishes to distinguish between Red Hat and CentOS, then idioms such as ```[ -f /etc/redhat-release ] && [ ! -h /etc/redhat-release ]``` could be used. Similarly with others.

Answer (score 14):

Following command worked out for me nicely. It gives you the OS name and version.

```
lsb_release -a
```

Answer (score 10):

The "lsb_release" command provides a certain [Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) (LSB) and distribution-specific information.

So using the below command we can get the Operating system name and operating system version.

"**lsb_release -a**"

Comment: This is not reliable in recent versions of RHEL/OEL/CentOS.

Answer (score 5):

This command gives you a description of your operating system:

`cat /etc/os-release`

Comment: What if it's not Linux, or not using systemd?

Answer (score 3):

In every distribution, it has different files, so I list the most common ones:

```
---- CentOS Linux distribution
`cat /proc/version`

---- Debian Linux distribution
`cat /etc/debian_version`

---- Redhat Linux distribution
`cat /etc/redhat-release`

---- Ubuntu Linux distribution
`cat /etc/issue`   or   `cat /etc/lsb-release`
```

In the last one, */etc/issue* didn't exist, so I tried the second one and it returned the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

**With quotes:**

```
cat /etc/*-release | grep "PRETTY_NAME" | sed 's/PRETTY_NAME=//g'
```

gives output as:

```
"CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
```

**Without quotes:**

```
cat /etc/*-release | grep "PRETTY_NAME" | sed 's/PRETTY_NAME=//g' | sed 's/"//g'
```

gives output as:

```
CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
```

Comment: What is up with the quotes?

Comment: @PeterMortensen in /etc/*-release file original value is stored with double quotes. if you want to save it in database most probably you would want to remove those double quotes as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) and [Linux::Distribution](https://metacpan.org/pod/Linux::Distribution), the cleanest solution for an old problem:

```
#!/bin/sh

perl -e '
    use Linux::Distribution qw(distribution_name distribution_version);

    my $linux = Linux::Distribution->new;
    if(my $distro = $linux->distribution_name()) {
          my $version = $linux->distribution_version();
          print "you are running $distro";
          print " version $version" if $version;
          print "\n";
    } else {
          print "distribution unknown\n";
    }
'
```

Comment: Post edited accordingly. You have to install perl's module `Linux::Distribution`

Comment: `liblinux-distribution-perl` package for debian & derivatives

Answer (score 1):

My own take at [@kvivek's script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26988390/586229), with more easily machine parsable output:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Outputs OS Name, Version & misc. info in a machine-readable way.
# See also NeoFetch for a more professional and elaborate bash script:
# https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch

SEP=","
PRINT_HEADER=false

print_help() {

    echo "`basename $0` - Outputs OS Name, Version & misc. info"
    echo "in a machine-readable way."
    echo
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "    `basename $0` [OPTIONS]"
    echo "Options:"
    echo "    -h, --help           print this help message"
    echo "    -n, --names          print a header line, naming the fields"
    echo "    -s, --separator SEP  overrides the default field-separator ('$SEP') with the supplied one"
}

# parse command-line args
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    arg="$1"
    shift # past switch

    case "${arg}" in
        -h|--help)
            print_help
            exit 0
            ;;
        -n|--names)
            PRINT_HEADER=true
            ;;
        -s|--separator)
            SEP="$1"
            shift # past value
            ;;
        *) # non-/unknown option
            echo "Unknown switch '$arg'" >&2
            print_help
            ;;
    esac
done

OS=`uname -s`
DIST="N/A"
REV=`uname -r`
MACH=`uname -m`
PSUEDONAME="N/A"

GetVersionFromFile()
{
    VERSION=`cat $1 | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/.*VERSION.*=\ // `
}

if [ "${OS}" = "SunOS" ] ; then
    DIST=Solaris
    DIST_VER=`uname -v`
    # also: cat /etc/release
elif [ "${OS}" = "AIX" ] ; then
    DIST="${OS}"
    DIST_VER=`oslevel -r`
elif [ "${OS}" = "Linux" ] ; then
    if [ -f /etc/redhat-release ] ; then
        DIST='RedHat'
        PSUEDONAME=`sed -e 's/.*\(//' -e 's/\)//' /etc/redhat-release `
        DIST_VER=`sed -e 's/.*release\ //' -e 's/\ .*//' /etc/redhat-release `
    elif [ -f /etc/SuSE-release ] ; then
        DIST=`cat /etc/SuSE-release | tr "\n" ' '| sed s/VERSION.*//`
        DIST_VER=`cat /etc/SuSE-release | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/.*=\ //`
    elif [ -f /etc/mandrake-release ] ; then
        DIST='Mandrake'
        PSUEDONAME=`sed -e 's/.*\(//' -e 's/\)//' /etc/mandrake-release`
        DIST_VER=`sed -e 's/.*release\ //' -e 's/\ .*//' /etc/mandrake-release`
    elif [ -f /etc/debian_version ] ; then
        DIST="Debian"
        DIST_VER=`cat /etc/debian_version`
    PSUEDONAME=`lsb_release -a 2> /dev/null | grep '^Codename:' | sed -e 's/.*[[:space:]]//'`
    #elif [ -f /etc/gentoo-release ] ; then
        #TODO
    #elif [ -f /etc/slackware-version ] ; then
        #TODO
    elif [ -f /etc/issue ] ; then
        # We use this indirection because /etc/issue may look like
    # "Debian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l"
        ISSUE=`cat /etc/issue`
        ISSUE=`echo -e "${ISSUE}" | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]\+$//'`
        DIST=`echo -e "${ISSUE}" | sed -e 's/[[:space:]].*//'`
        DIST_VER=`echo -e "${ISSUE}" | sed -e 's/.*[[:space:]]//'`
    fi
    if [ -f /etc/UnitedLinux-release ] ; then
        DIST="${DIST}[`cat /etc/UnitedLinux-release | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/VERSION.*//`]"
    fi
    # NOTE `sed -e 's/.*(//' -e 's/).*//' /proc/version`
    #      is an option that worked ~ 2010 and earlier
fi

if $PRINT_HEADER
then
    echo "OS${SEP}Distribution${SEP}Distribution-Version${SEP}Pseudo-Name${SEP}Kernel-Revision${SEP}Machine-Architecture"
fi
echo "${OS}${SEP}${DIST}${SEP}${DIST_VER}${SEP}${PSUEDONAME}${SEP}${REV}${SEP}${MACH}"
```

**NOTE**: Only tested on Debian 11

### Example Runs

#### No args

```sh
osInfo
```

output:

```
Linux,Debian,10.0,buster,4.19.0-5-amd64,x86_64
```

#### Header with names and custom separator

```sh
osInfo --names -s "\t| "
```

output:

```
OS  | Distribution  | Distribution-Version  | Pseudo-Name   | Kernel-Revision   | Machine-Architecture
Linux   | Debian    | 10.0  | buster    | 4.19.0-5-amd64    | x86_64
```

#### Filtered output

```sh
osInfo | awk -e 'BEGIN { FS=","; } { print $2 " " $3 " (" $4 ")" }'
```

output:

```
Debian 10.0 (buster)
```

Answer (score 1):

I prepared the following commands to find concise information about a Linux system:

```
clear
echo "\n----------OS Information------------"
hostnamectl | grep "Static hostname:"
hostnamectl | tail -n 3
echo "\n----------Memory Information------------"
cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal
echo "\n----------CPU Information------------"
echo -n "Number of core(s): "
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "processor" | wc -l
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" | head -n 1
echo "\n----------Disk Information------------"
echo -n "Total Size: "
df -h --total | tail -n 1| awk '{print $2}'
echo -n "Used: "
df -h --total | tail -n 1| awk '{print $3}'
echo -n "Available: "
df -h --total | tail -n 1| awk '{print $4}'
echo "\n-------------------------------------\n"
```

Copy and paste in an *sh* file, like *info.sh*, and then run it using command *sh info.sh*.

Comment: While this gets information that may be useful, it doesn't answer the question (getting the OS name and version)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best and easiest way to find the OS name and kernel version. It is also supported in all Linux flavors.

```
VERSION=`cat /proc/version`
echo $VERSION
```