# How to find linux os version?

Tags: linux

I've tried multiple commands of linux but it doesn't work. And also I've tried some more windows command still it doesn't work . If some one can help me in this

Comment: `cat /etc/os-release` or `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to find os name and version in Unix/Linux platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988262/best-way-to-find-os-name-and-version-in-unix-linux-platform)

Answer (score 0):

Try `hostnamectl` or `uname -r`
You can see 'Kernel' field with the linux version.